# How to merge groups permissions in aem for user

Tags: aem, permission-denied, aem-6

How can merged multiple groups permissions for user

product1,product2,product3 pages is not displaying to user, if user is part of Goups A,B,C

```
Group A has below paths permissions--> 
      content/abc/product1 **allow**
      content/abc/product2 **deny**
      content/abc/product3 **deny**

Group B has below paths permissions--> 
      content/abc/product1 **deny**
      content/abc/product2 **allow**
      content/abc/product3 **deny**

Group C has below paths permissions--> 
      content/abc/product1 **deny**
      content/abc/product2 **deny**
      content/abc/product3 **allow**
```

I want to display product1,product2,product3 if user is part of Goups A,B,C

Comment: I don't have time to answer now. But the order of permissions on a node stores that. They are evaluated from bottom to top. So the the deny rule should be the first, and the allow rules the last. As soons as Jackrabbit found a matching rule, this rule is taken. So the allow-rules are found first, and adding up. -- I try to give a complete answer next week.

Comment: https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/security/permission/evaluation.html